# WxFreechart - adding scroll bar to bottom axis and left axis

Tags: c++, charts, scrollbar, wxwidgets

I am using `wxfreechart` to generate a chart from my input dataset. The bottom axis is a `DateAxis` and the left axis is a `NumberAxis`. I was able to set scroll bar for my bottom axis. I need to set scroll bar for left axis too.. Adding it using `setscrolledaxis()` creates the scroll bar, but the chart becomes very unclear with no labels and all. Can anybody help me :(

Also the scrolling doesn't happen unless scroll bar is dragged using mouse.Clicking on the scroll arrows moves the scroll bar very slowly, but the chart window does not move accordingly. Any solution?

Comment: What's your compiler (MVC++ or MinGW) ? Sometimes when there are odd behaviours there is somewhere a mix between 32bits and 64bits library, or one library was compiled in debug mode and one was in release mode.

Comment: What's your version of wxWidget ?

Comment: @NGI: I am using MSVS2010 and wxwidgets 3.0.0. I have checked the build configuration of libraries and is the same mode.

Comment: Can I get some help?